# Zend framework rendering custom place holders in layout

Tags: zend-framework, layout, render, placeholder

I have some custom place holders in layout file, like [Region_Contents]
now I want to replace these placeholders with my custom html as layout is rendered
like instead of displaying [Region_Contents] it may show

## Hello this is test block

is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use view filters for this.  First we have to implement the Zend_Filter_Interface like so:

```
class My_View_Filter_PlaceholderReplacer implements Zend_Filter_Interface
{
    public function filter($value) 
    {
        return str_replace('[Region_Contents]', 'Hello this is test block', $value);
    }
}
```

In the code above, $value contains the string representation of the view just before it is displayed.  Whatever is returned by the function above will be used by ZF when rendering the view.  Note that we're using str_replace over preg_replace for performance reasons.

Next, we need to tell ZF to use the filter we just made.  You can do this in the bootstrap.

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
  protected function _initViewSettings()
  {
    $this->bootstrap('view');
    $view = $this->getResource('view');
    $view->addFilterPath('My/View/Filter', 'My_View_Filter');
    $view->setFilter('PlaceholderReplacer');
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

For more info, please refer to the following links:

[Zend Manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.5/en/zend.filter.writing_filters.html)

[Zend Framework and Translation](http://devzone.zend.com/article/4513)

Comment: I want to filter layout only, I don't want to filter the view. in above case it is filtering both view and layout but i need to filter only layout

Answer (score 0):

If it's not necessary to keep the same syntax you describe above, you might just use the standard `Zend_View` placeholder view helpers: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.placeholder

Hope that helps,